# Passing the size of a 2D array to a function?

Tags: c

The assignment is to write a program that takes in strings from command line input and sets them all separately to an array of strings.Then for each string check if it uppercase or lowercase and convert the letter to the opposite case.

Example:

`Input: Hello Sir How Are You?`
`Output: hELLO sIR hOW aRE yOU?`

I am currently stuck on trying to loop through the array of strings to check each character to see if it is uppercase or lowercase. It has to be a seperate function `togglecase()` that takes the string array and returns the desired output.

```
char** toggle_case(char *data[], int size){

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            printf("%s\n",&data[i][j] );

        }
        printf("\n");
    }

return data;
}
```

This is where I have gotten. So the function `togglecase()` should be taking an 2D array of strings  where `data[0][0]` would be the first word and first character of that word. I am having a hard time trying to figure out how I can get the size of the words. I can pass the size of the array but the amount of characters in each string is the issue. I can figure out how to toggle the case after that. It needs to return the array that has been changed as well.

Comment: shouldn't that be `data[0][0]` ? Can't you just use `strlen()` for the length?

Comment: I was just using data[1][1] as an example. It is not the first word.

Comment: Yes you can just use `strlen()`. I did not even think of that. Thank you.

Comment: Assuming a 2D array, your parameter should be `char (*data)[ncols]` -- and if that is so, then the return type of `char **` is incorrect. However if you have dynamically allocated storage for pointers and for each string, then `char**` would be correct. Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Additionally, why should `togglecase` output or return anything? Shouldn't it just loop over each char in each word and toggle the case of each character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'\0'` character can be used for marking the end of a string word. Then you can use `strlen(data[i])` or just iterate over the data[i] till you find the `'\0'` to find the length.

For example,
`for (int j = 0; data[i][j] != '\0'; j++)`

In order to do this, when `data[i]` is populated initially, the `'\0'` should be added at the end. If you have used functions like `scanf()` to take the input, it automatically does that.